# Pandas groupby on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following table:

[image]

I'm attempting to do two things with the table:

1) If a call only appears once, make it so that any of these single-call entries that also have a zipcode entry get a 1 under order.

```
#work with unique data
import pandas as pd

def order_chk(x):
    if pd.isnull(x['ORDER_TIMESTAMP']) or pd.isnull(x['ZIP']):
        return 0
    return 1

calls_t = calls.groupby('ANI').filter(lambda x: len(x) < 2).apply(lambda row: order_chk(row), axis=1)
```

2) It gets trickier when there are two calls but only one order; in these cases i want the call that was closer to the order to get the 1 under the order column (the delta column is timedelta objects)

So final table looks like this (yellow shading to show the 1)

[image]

Let me know if I can clarify anything, I have a feeling I'm missing something really silly with .apply on groups.

```
    DATE    TIMESTAMP   ANI DNIS    VENDOR  ORDER_TIMESTAMP ZIP delta   ORDER   CALLS
0   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 00:19:09 7249534228  8009894581  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
1   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 00:19:10 9207482180  8009894581  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
2   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 00:19:22 2405870965  8009894581  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
3   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 00:19:29 6192537800  8009894581  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
4   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 00:21:00 2405870965  8009894581  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
5   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 11:31:19 9857140062  8009136242  ACE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
6   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 12:50:12 5802260487  8009137764  ACE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
7   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 14:13:08 Unavailable 8009135189  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
8   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 16:29:13 7172665487  8009140816  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
9   7/13/2016   2016-07-13 17:02:25 8079819744  8009131719  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
10  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 19:21:54 8435466441  8009135302  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
11  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 20:41:28 9063462078  8009894581  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
12  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 20:50:19 6143772125  8009084876  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
13  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 20:50:20 8148563460  8009084876  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
14  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 20:50:22 5616837515  8009084876  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
15  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 20:53:07 9032270226  8009084876  CORNERSTONE NaT NaN NaT 0   1
16  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 23:58:38 9283779292  8009131653  CORNERSTONE 2016-07-13 23:59:26 223032109   00:00:48    0   1
17  7/13/2016   2016-07-13 21:14:08 9283779292  8009131653  CORNERSTONE 2016-07-13 23:59:26 223032109   02:45:18    0   1
```

Comment: Please do not post data as png... use text. So, people can cut and paste the code.

Comment: What happens when you run your existing groupby code? Why does that not work?

Comment: I've included a table with the text. I used a PNG because the column formatting makes it very hard to read the actual contents on SO. Sorry! -Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the first part works for you, and for the second part you want to mark the lines with the lowest delta value (per call).
The following code fetched the line numbers of these calls, and then assigns ORDER=1 on those lines.

```
cond = calls.groupby(['ANI'])['delta'].transform(min) == df['delta']
calls.loc[cond, 'ORDER'] = 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi just following up here, I jumped the gun on accepting the solution. I had assumed it would work because it intuitively made sense in my head. I'm instead getting an error because it can't handle NaT values, as follows: "    688             # integer comparisons
    689             if is_datetimelike_v_numeric(x, y):
--> 690                 raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
    691 
    692             # numpy does not like comparisons vs None
TypeError: invalid type comparison". Is there a way to suppress the typeerror?

Comment: I haven't tested the answer above; but if you are just trying to avoid numpy complaining about NaT values, `````calls.delta.fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))````` will substitute the NaTs, while preserving the consistency of the dtype in the ````delta```` column.